# sed or perl + inserting text between two lines

Tags: sed

I have the following file: (example.txt  showing down)

I need to edit the file , the main issue is to append  text between two known lines in the file

first_line=")"

second_line="NIC Hr_Nic ("

For example

Need to add the following:

```
    haattr -add RVG StorageRVG -string
    haattr -add RVG StorageDG -string
    haattr -add RVG StorageHostIds -string
    haattr -delete RVG Primary
    haattr -delete RVG SRL
    haattr -delete RVG RLinks
```

Between

The first match line ")"

And the

second match line "NIC Hr_Nic ("

As described in example.txt file

How to do this by sed ... (If its difficult by sed it can also possible with perl)

remark (sed need to get two arguments 
       the first argument is the first match line (first_line arg)
       the second argument is the second match line (second_line arg)

example.txt file:

```
    group Hr_Grp (
    SystemList = { london1 = 0, london2 = 1 }
    AutoStartList = { london1, london2 }
    )

    NIC Hr_Nic (
            Device = qfe0
            )

    IP Hr_Ip(
            Device = qfe0
            Address = "1.1.1.1"         // Virtual IP
            )

    DiskGroup Hr_Dg(
            DiskGroup = hrdg
            )

    RVG Hr_Rvg (
            RVG = hr_rvg
            DiskGroup = hrdg
            )

    Hr_Rvg requires Hr_Dg
    Hr_Rvg requires Hr_Ip
    Hr_Ip requires Hr_Nic
```

Example of the file after sed edit:

```
    group Hr_Grp (
    SystemList = { london1 = 0, london2 = 1 }
    AutoStartList = { london1, london2 }
    )


    haattr -add RVG StorageRVG -string
    haattr -add RVG StorageDG -string
    haattr -add RVG StorageHostIds -string
    haattr -delete RVG Primary
    haattr -delete RVG SRL
    haattr -delete RVG RLinks



    NIC Hr_Nic (
            Device = qfe0
            )

    IP Hr_Ip(
            Device = qfe0
            Address = "1.1.1.1"         // Virtual IP
            )

    DiskGroup Hr_Dg(
            DiskGroup = hrdg
            )

    RVG Hr_Rvg (
            RVG = hr_rvg
            DiskGroup = hrdg
            )

    Hr_Rvg requires Hr_Dg
    Hr_Rvg requires Hr_Ip
    Hr_Ip requires Hr_Nic
```

Comment: So what's the question? Or did you want us to code it for you? What do you have so far?

Comment: the main target is to append text between two lines with sed or perl?

Comment: I know how to append test before line or after line 
But I don't know how to append text between two matched lines -:(

Comment: the examples here is only to clear my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
text=$(<file)
sed -e '/[[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]*/{:a;n;/NIC Hr_Nic (/i\' -e "$text" -e 'ba}'
```

I'm using `i` for insert and a variable since the `r` (read file) command does an append after the current line. You can also set the variable like this:

```
read -d '' -r text<<EOF
haattr -add RVG StorageRVG -string
haattr -add RVG StorageDG -string
etc.
EOF
```

or

```
text="haattr -add RVG StorageRVG -string
haattr -add RVG StorageDG -string
etc."
```